# Is java required in order to get webdriver-manager to start?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

When I run webdriver-manager start.
I run into the error message "Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn java ENOENT"
Do I need to Install java? If so how would I do so on a chrome book that is running crostini?

Your answers or pointers would be much appreciated!.

```
webdriver-manager start
[03:35:35] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0 -jar /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[03:35:35] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined
[03:35:35] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn java ENOENT
```

Comment: You need to install JDK and set the java path

Comment: Awsome I was able to do this following the instructions from : 
https://www.javahelps.com/2017/09/install-oracle-jdk-9-on-linux.html

I am running crostini on  chromebook spin 11

Answer (score 2):

The Selenium requires Java. Download the latest JDK and set the `path`. Read more about how to coding and set up your Chromebook here:

- [Coding with a Chromebook](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/coding-with-a-chromebook/197893/4)
- [How To Run Full Java 8 On Your Chromebook](https://www.meetchrome.com/java-on-chromebook/)
- [Get Java on your Chromebook](https://platypusplatypus.com/chromebooks/enable-java/)

Comment: The first link was helpful as it clarified that I can indeed run many programs including Java JDK on crostini.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The Selenium requires Java for its operations.

Download the latest JDK and set the environment, make sure node.js installed properly and installed protractor globally (npm install -g protractor), then try again.